# How to find similar tree in JSON format

Tags: json, tree, olap

I have a table that has 2 columns, Id and Tree. The Tree column is a JSON document (about 5 in deep and about 10 in wide). The number of rows could be a billion. I need a query that returns similar Trees with a specified Tree. "Similar" Trees have the same structure, but there is one or two node value is different. I think my solution should come up with OLAP or something like that, but I don't know how to get it. Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please clearify your question: 
you are programming with which language? which ide? which kind of olap? Could you give a small example of your code until now? That would make it a lot easier to answer your question :)

Comment: Any language is appreciated. Any OLAP also is appreciated. Current my table is stored in Microsoft SQL Server 2008. Here is my small example `var similarTrees = context.query("json text here");`